# Prove the Cartesian product of two finite sets is finite without using cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am using ZFC and the following definitions:

$x$ is finite iff it is in bijection with a natural number;

$x$ is infinite iff it contains an injective image of $\omega$, the set of natural numbers.

Alternatively, we also have the following definition for finite:

A set $x$ is finite if every nonempty element of the power-set of x has an inclusion minimal element.

How can this be proved making use of these definitions? Note, cardinality has not been introduced at this point.

Comment: "$x$ is finite iff it is in bijection with a natural number."  Why not use then that $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$ for finite sets $A$ and $B$.  If $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$, why not come up with an explicit bijection between $A\times B$ and $[ab]$?

Comment: @JMoravitz note the fact that cardinality hasn't come up yet my guess is it's for a class and they should show some effort.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are finite, we can find natural numbers $n$ and $m$ and bijections $f:A\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $g:B\to\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Using $f$ and $g$, can we find a bijection $h:A\times B\to\{1,\ldots,nm\}$?

Comment: We don't know what *have* come up in class already. Did you learn induction? Induction on finite sets style Kuratowski? Something else?

Comment: @AsafKaragila We have learned induction!

Comment: Do you have available the fact that a set is finite iff it's not infinite? I.e., a set is finite iff it contains no injective image of $\omega$? If so, you could prove that the product of two finite sets is finite by showing that, if the product $A\times B$ contains an injective image of $\omega,$ then one of the factors contains an injective image of $\omega.$

Comment: How do you propose to do "without using cardinality" when the _very definition_ of the concept you want to prove something about says "in bijection with"? Cardinality is nothing more or less than a sometimes more suggestive way to say "in bijection with".

Answer (score 2):

Let both $X_1$ and $X_2$ be finite sets with bijective maps

$\tag 1 \sigma_1: X_1 \to n_1 $
$\tag 2 \sigma_2: X_2 \to n_2 $

to the natural numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$.

The [Cartesian product of the functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions) $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ gives a bijection

$\tag 3 \sigma_1 \times \sigma_2: X_1 \times X_2 \to  n_1 \times n_2 $

If you have defined the product of two natural numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ then you know that $n_1 n_2$ can be put into a bijective correspondence with $n_1 \times n_2$. If you only have addition, then you have some more work to do.

The successor function $S$ can be used to define the [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Multiplication) of the natural numbers once you have addition 'bijectively nailed as a disjoint union'.

For multiplication,

$\tag 4 a × 0 = 0$

$\tag 5 a × S(b) = (a × b) + a$

and you 'nail down' the product $a \times b$ of two natural numbers to the cartesian product of two finite sets. Of course this brings us right back to Asaf's answer:

$\tag 6 A\times(B\cup\{\hat b\})=(A\times B)\cup(A\times\{\hat b\}) \; \; \hat b \notin B$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $A$. Now you can prove this by induction on the cardinality of $B$, noting that the base case, $B$ with $0$ elements, is trivial (what is $A\times\varnothing$?), and by proving that $A\times(B\cup\{b\})=(A\times B)\cup(A\times\{b\})$ when $b\notin B$.

Of course, this is predicated on you already knowing that the union of two finite sets is finite. If you have not proved that yet, you should prove this as well, and this is also done by induction.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you're willing to look again at your answer, would you be willing to clarify which set you're performing induction on? Is it something like $\{n \in \omega \mid |B| = n \Rightarrow A \times B \text{ is finite} \}$?

Comment: As the first line says. We fixed $A$ and we prove by induction on $|B|$.

Comment: Doesn't $A\times(B\cup\{b\})=(A\times B)\cup(A\times\{b\})$ regardless of if $b\in B$?

Comment: @lilyboo: Yes, and how does $b\in B$ help you towards your proof by induction?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other solutions, but a bit more rigour..
I'll assume we know that the union of finite sets is finite.
Let $n,m$ be natural numbers.
Then $n$x$\{m\}$ is finite because $f:n$x$\{m\}\rightarrow n$ defined by $f:(<x,y>)=x$ is a bijection.  (1).
We know $n$x$∅=∅$ and $∅$ is finite. Assume $n$x$k$ is finite, $k$ a natural number. Now $n$x$k^+=n$x$(k \cup \{k \})=(n$x$k) \cup (n$x$\{k\})$. By our induction hypothesis $n$x$k$ is finite. By result (1), $n$x$\{k\}$ is finite. And because the union of finite sets is finite, we know $n$x$k^+$ is finite and so by induction $n$x$m$ is finite for natural numbers $n,m$.
Now assume $A$ and $B$ are finite. Then there are natural numbers $n,m$ and bijections $f,g$ such that $f:A\rightarrow n$ and $g:B\rightarrow m$ We know $h:A$x$B\rightarrow n$x$m$ defined by $h(<x,y>)=<f(x),g(y)>$ is a bijection. And we know $n$x$m$ is finite, so there is a natural number $r$, and a bijection $p$ such that $p:n$x$m\rightarrow r$. And the composition of two bijective functions is a bijection so $p \circ h:A$x$B \rightarrow r$ is a bijection and $A$x$B$ is a finite set.